# Calculate Delta between time series peaks with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, delta

I have two pandas dataframe as follow:

df1:

| dt | z |
| --- | --- |
| 1970-01-17 21:39:10.304 | 0.87602 |
| 1970-01-17 21:39:10.344 | 0.99907 |
| ... | ... |

df2:
| dt                        | z               |
| --------------------------| --------------  |
| 1970-01-17 21:39:23.312   | 0.84904         |
| 1970-01-17 21:39:23.352   | 1.00542         |
| ...                       | ...             |

where dt is the index and z (that has values between 0 and 2) is the only column, in order to plot timeseries.
I have plotted the two time series:
[image: time series plot]

Both dataframe should have approximately the same values since both registers the same event. The problem is the time delay with which they record the values.

I need to calculate the delta between the time series in time order, is it possible starting from the dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit accorind to OPs update.

Comments in code.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta


# sample data for two data frames
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.rand(20) + 1,
    columns=["col"],
    index=pd.date_range(
        start="2023-04-01T00:00",
        end="2023-04-07T00:00",
        periods=20)
)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.random.rand(20) + 1,
    columns=["col"],
    index=pd.date_range(
        start="2023-04-01T00:00",
        end="2023-04-07T00:00",
        periods=20)
)

# choose according to your needs
offset_threshold = timedelta(days=1, hours=6)

# choose according to your needs
peak_strength_threshold = 1.8

# highlight peaks by applying some threshold or "peak detection"
df1["peak"] = df1["col"] > peak_strength_threshold
df2["peak"] = df2["col"] > peak_strength_threshold

for index1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    if row1.peak:
        # find matching peak in df2
        df2_peaks = df2[df2.peak]
        best_match_in_df2 = df2_peaks.iloc[np.abs((df2_peaks.index - index1)).argmin()]

        delta = index1 - best_match_in_df2.name

        # check if the best match is close enough to be published
        if np.abs(delta) < offset_threshold:
            print(delta)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have modified the question since it was unclear, i need to calculate tue time delay between the two dataframes, since they should have the same pattern

Comment: thanks, so it work for you if there was a nearest-peak matching to calculate the offsets and a threshold to filter out false-positive matches?

Comment: yes, it should work fine